# race condition in my java mail web client,while multiple account acssess it

Tags: java, tomcat7, jakarta-mail, race-condition

I'm trying to build web based email client using javamail api.but I'm facing race condition issues while multiple users trying to accesses their inbox.

my connection class looks like this
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
public IMAPConnection(String host, String username, String password) throws NoSuchProviderException {
     synchronized (this) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.host = host;
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", host);
        properties.setProperty("mail.imap.partialfetch", "false");
        properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
        properties.setProperty("mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors", "true");
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        IMAPConnection.store=session.getStore(isSSLEnabled ? imapProtocol : "imap");
     }  
}

public synchronized boolean DagooIMAPConnection() throws NoSuchProviderException, MessagingException {
    boolean connected = false;
    try {

        store.connect(host, username, password);
        connected = true;
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        connected = false;
    }
    return connected;
}
```

}

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
and the imap fetching class

++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```java
public class GetUserMail {
    private static String host = ReadConfigPropertiesFile.getPropertyValue("geezmail.host");
    private static int itemsPerPage = Integer.parseInt(ReadConfigPropertiesFile.getPropertyValue("emails.perpage"));
    private static Message[] message = null;
    private static Message singlemessage = null;
    private int totalEmails = 0;
    private int newMsgCnt = 0;
    private int newspamCnt = 0;
    private int start = 0;
    private int end = 0;
    public Folder folder = null;
    private String mailFolder;
    public static IMAPConnection con;

    public GetUserMail(String username, String password, String mailFolder) throws NoSuchProviderException, MessagingException {
            this.mailFolder = mailFolder;
            con = new IMAPConnection(host, username, password);
    }

    public synchronized Message[] GetUserSelectedMail() throws NoSuchProviderException, MessagingException {
        Message[] message2 = null;

        if (con.DagooIMAPConnection()) {
            try {
                folder = con.store.getFolder(mailFolder);
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    folder.create(1);
                }
                if (!folder.isOpen()) {
                    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
                }
                end = folder.getMessageCount();
                start = end - itemsPerPage;
                if (end >= itemsPerPage) {
                    message2 = folder.getMessages(start + 1, end);
                } else {
                    message2 = folder.getMessages();
                }
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                System.out.println("Internal Server Erro: 500");
            }
            //order messages in reverse - from newest to oldest
            int k = message2.length - 1;
            message = new Message[message2.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < message2.length; j++, k--) {
                message[j] = message2[k];
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Couldnt connect to server");
        }
        return message;
    }

    public synchronized Message[] GetCurserSelectedMail(int start1) throws NoSuchProviderException, MessagingException {
        Message[] message2 = null;

        if (con.DagooIMAPConnection()) {
            try {
                folder = con.store.getFolder(mailFolder);
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    folder.create(1);
                }
                if (!folder.isOpen()) {
                    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
                }
                end = folder.getMessageCount();
                if (end >= itemsPerPage) {
                    message2 = folder.getMessages(start1 + 1, end);
                } else {
                    message2 = folder.getMessages();
                }
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                System.out.println("Internal Server Erro: 500");
            }
            //order messages in reverse - from newest to oldest
            int k = message2.length - 1;
            message = new Message[message2.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < message2.length; j++, k--) {
                message[j] = message2[k];
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Couldnt connect to server");
        }
        return message;
    }

    public synchronized Message GetUserMailOrdered(int UID) throws NoSuchProviderException, MessagingException {
        try {
            if (con.DagooIMAPConnection()) {
                folder = con.store.getFolder(mailFolder);
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    folder.create(1);
                }
                if (!folder.isOpen()) {
                    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
                }
                singlemessage = folder.getMessage(UID);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Couldnt connect to server");
            }
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            System.out.println("Internal Server Erro: 500");
        }

        return singlemessage;
    }

    public synchronized int GetNewMessageCount() {

        try {
            if (con.DagooIMAPConnection()) {

                folder = con.store.getFolder(mailFolder);
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    folder.create(1);
                }
                if (!folder.isOpen()) {
                    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
                }
                newMsgCnt = folder.getUnreadMessageCount();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Couldnt connect to database");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }

        return newMsgCnt;
    }

    public synchronized int GetNewMessageCountspm() {
        try {
            if (con.DagooIMAPConnection()) {
                folder = con.store.getFolder("Spam");
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    folder.create(1);
                }
                if (!folder.isOpen()) {
                    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
                }
                newspamCnt = folder.getUnreadMessageCount();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Couldnt connect to database");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }

        return newspamCnt;
    }

    public synchronized int GetTotalEmailsCount() {
        try {
            if (con.DagooIMAPConnection()) {
                folder = con.store.getFolder(mailFolder);
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    folder.create(1);
                }
                if (!folder.isOpen()) {
                    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
                }
                totalEmails = folder.getMessageCount();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Couldnt connect to database");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        return totalEmails;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change all the `static` members to instance members, except perhaps the `host` variable, and make sure every thread uses its own instance of your classes. I don't see any reason for many of the data items to be member variables at all, for example the `Message[]` array.